# CJMCU-116 9DOF mpu9250 driver

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c

I've recently bought a CJMCU-116 sensor equipped with MPU9250. It features magnetometer, accelerometer and gyroscope. It uses I2C for communication.
I've scouted everywhere but I could not find any library to make it work properly, just one that seems to work but I'm not 100% sure.
Can someone point me to the right direction, please?

 I'm using [this library](https://github.com/sparkfun/SparkFun_MPU-9250-DMP_Arduino_Library)
found [here](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/9dof-razor-imu-m0-hookup-guide/using-the-mpu-9250-dmp-arduino-library).
 I know this is not the same sensor but the chip is the same, so it should work, am I right?

Comment: "Seems to work" but you're not sure...? Either it works or it doesn't. Which is it?

Comment: It reads values but sometimes suddenly stop working, even though everything is connected. I've updated the question with the links to the libraries.

Comment: The make and model number of the sensor is of no importance. It's just a PCB to hold the chip and power circuitry. Maybe it's your wiring. I2C can be iffy and lock up with loose connections.

Comment: So it's enough to get a driver for the MPU9250 regardless the sensor?

Comment: Yep. It's the chip you're communicating with, not the board.

Comment: Well, I suppose this would be of great help, thank you, I'll keep you posted!

Comment: If you use a 5V Arduino board without level shifter for the I2C, then the MPU-9250 might have been damaged by now. The Sparkfun library was the first thing that came to my mind. You can use that library. How long are the I2C wires ? what kind of cable do you use for I2C ? Use seperate wires without cable and a maximum of 50 cm for the I2C.

Comment: I'm using 20cm jumper wires male/female and I'm powering the sensor with 3.3v. Why do you think it could have been damaged?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seeks to find an external resource in the form of a library.